# Windows 10 offline <-> network drive nightmare

Tags: network-share, windows-10, hangs

I'm banging my head against the walls due to a very weird problem we have at my company.

First of all, my problem occurs only on **W10** workstations (no matter the hardware, the build version or with GPOs enabled/disabled) AND our clustered file servers (2012R2) (it doesn't happen when connected to a simple 2012R2 file share - didn't had time to test on our database cluster).

Here is the problem : when a workstation has a network drive mounted and is disconnected from network (unplug the cable), the OS is constantly trying to reach out for the file server instead of marking the drive as disconnected after a few attempts. The pc becomes slow and irresponsive until the network comes back. Since we have for example Word configured to save files in the network drive by default, users are unable to save a document because word is just waiting forever for the network drive to become accessible again.

I haven't found any clue on the internet, except a topic with no solution and our IT consulting firm hasn't found a solution either.

Comment: What is it you are expecting to happen? If a network drive is mapped and becomes disconnected and you keep trying to access it, the application is going to wait for that to fail every time. That’s not unusual. Any chance you are also doing folder redirection to a network share, specifically appdata? This also breaks best practice and will cause severe performance issues.

Comment: That's not true. On my W7 workstations, the OS tries a few times to reach the server before giving up and marking the drive as disconnected (red cross). There is no folder redirection, just Word's default save path linking to the network drive. Again, on W7, Word tries to connect for a few seconds before giving up and reverting to "My documents". On W10 (with our file servers only, because if mapped to a standard server share it works fine), the OS/Word constantly tries to contact the server without giving up after some time.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I would also prefer Win10 to just stop trying the bloody offline drive and let me reconnect to it manually when I know its online.